# How to configure Ebean clustering?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I want to use [Ebean's L2 cache](https://ebean.io/docs/features/l2cache/). The problem is I have multiple instances of service all looking at the same database, so I need a way to invalidate the cache across the cluster. If an object was updated on one of the instances, other instances should learn about it and update their caches.

There are mentions of something like this in the [documentation](https://ebean.io/docs/features/l2cache/):

> L2 near caches are invalidated across the cluster very quickly
>
> The message sent around the cluster contains the table name and boolean flags for insert, update and delete.

But I couldn't find any instructions on how to set it up neither in the documentation nor on the internet. The best thing I found is the following probably outdated [snippet](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/623):

```
ebean.cluster.active=true
ebean.cluster.localHostPort=127.0.0.1:9942
ebean.cluster.members=127.0.0.1:9942,127.0.0.1:9943
```

I think it is outdated because there is no `ebean.cluster.members` property in my version of Ebean. I'm using Ebean 11.15.4 with Play Framework 2.6.23 and play-ebean 4.1.3.

Comment: Those properties are still correct assuming you are using ebean-cluster (which is a simple TCP socket based cluster).  It's different if you are using ebean-redis (which uses redis pub-sub), ebean-hazelcast (uses hazelcast to cluster), ebean-ignite (uses ignite to cluster).

Comment: In other words, that code that is now in the separate ebean-cluster artifact was previously included in the main/core ebean artifact.  So likely you just need to add ebean-cluster as a dependency.

Comment: @RobBygrave is there any documentation for all of these artifacts (ebean-cluster, ebean-redis, ebean-hazelcast, ebean-ignite)?